# error after imported google play service

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

Help me please,..
after i imported google play servoce into my eclipse  workspace, there are so many error in values under google play service. how to fix them ?
here is some error message :

```
14: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_network_error_text is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:22: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:15: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_invalid_account_title is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:23: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:16: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:24: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:17: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_unknown_issue is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:25: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:18: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_unsupported_title is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:26: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:19: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_unsupported_text is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:27: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:20: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_update_button is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:28: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:21: error: Resource entry common_signin_button_text is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:29: Originally defined here.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:22: error: Resource entry common_signin_button_text_long is already defined.
[2014-11-11 17:54:45 - TampilPeta] D:\Androidku\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\common_strings.xml:30: Originally defined here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you have imported it once ,see in the build path section of project and remove any previous imports.